# Upgrading pysqlite(sqlite3) module on windows

Tags: python, sqlite, pip, easy-install, pysqlite

I'm trying to upgrade the builtin module pysqlite(sqlite3) on my windows 7, to the most recent version (currently 2.8.2).
My python version is 2.7.10.

When I run the pip commend on my cmd console, I get the following message:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --upgrade pysqlite Collecting pysqlite
>   Using cached pysqlite-2.8.2.tar.gz Installing collected packages:
>   pysqlite   Running setup.py install for pysqlite ... error
>       Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-semsbd\pysqlite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\pip-fkkno1-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
>       copying lib\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
>       copying lib\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
>       copying lib__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\dbapi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\factory.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\hooks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\regression.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\transactions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test\userfunctions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       copying lib\test__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pysqlite2\test
>       running build_ext
>       building 'pysqlite2._sqlite' extension
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src
>       C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS-
>   /DNDEBUG -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite2.dbapi2\" -I'{' -Iis -Inot
>   -Irecognized -Ias -Ian -Iinternal -Ior -Iexternal -Icommand, -Ioperable -Iprogram -Ior -Ibatch -Ifile. "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda\PC"
>   /Tcsrc/module.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/module.obj
>       module.c
>       c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-semsbd\pysqlite\src\connection.h(33)
>   : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such
>   file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,
> ```
>
> tokenize;**file**='c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-semsbd\pysqlite\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\pip-fkkno1-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-semsbd\pysqlite\

So I tried using easy install, and got the following message:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install -U pysqlite Searching for pysqlite
>   Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pysqlite/ Best match: pysqlite
>   2.8.2 Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/cc/a4/023ee9dba54b3cf0c5a4d0fb2f1ad80332ef23549dd4b551a9f2cbe88786/pysqlite-2.8.2.tar.gz#md5=b8488f6a353bd6a3cd85d327d326376a
>   Processing pysqlite-2.8.2.tar.gz Writing
>   c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-jwrns4\pysqlite-2.8.2\setup.cfg
>   Running pysqlite-2.8.2\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir
>   c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-jwrns4\pysqlite-2.8.2\egg-dist-tmp-dw1hgi
>   warning: no files found matching 'doc*.txt' module.c
>   c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-jwrns4\pysqlite-2.8.2\src\connection.h(33)
>   : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sqlite3.h': No such
>   file or directory error: Setup script exited with error: command
>   'C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Any ideas how this module can be updated?

Thanks in advance!